# ООП Python __init__

Tags: python, ооп

Создайте класс Zebra, внутри которого есть метод which_stripe , который поочередно печатает фразы "Полоска белая", "Полоска черная", начиная именно с фразы "Полоска белая"

Пример работы с классом Zebra

z1 = Zebra()

z1.which_stripe() # печатает "Полоска белая"

z1.which_stripe() # печатает "Полоска черная"

z1.which_stripe() # печатает "Полоска белая"

z2 = Zebra()

z2.which_stripe() # печатает "Полоска белая"

Вот как пытался сделать сам, но не получается

```
class Zebra():
    def which_stripe(self, count = 0):
        self.count = count
        self.count = self.count + 1

        if self.count == 0:
            print('Полоска белssая')
        elif self.count % 2 == 0:   
            print('Полоска чёрная')
        elif self.count % 2 != 0:
            print('Полоска белая')
```

Comment: Начните писать код сами, если у вас появятся проблемы вам помогут. Здесь не пишут готовые решения с нуля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить в ваш класс счетчик привязанный к самому объекту:

```py
class Zebra:
    def __init__():
        self.i = 0
    def which_stripe():
        if self.i % 2 == 0:
            print('Полоска белая')
        else:
            print('Полоска чёрная')
        self.i += 1
```

Comment: @Jhartum тогда поставьте галочку слева от ответа)